# Move the position of company field before street in shipping form in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am using magento 2.2.6 i want to change the position of company field in billing and shipping form in checkout before street field.

i was trying following code but not worked

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Try this <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>

Comment: try rm -rf pub/static/* and redeploy your content

Comment: @PradeepSanku, If answer is helpful than please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some minor correction is required, See below code

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
</item>
```

If you made another changes like add or update field in UI than remove your UI Component entry from `"ui_bookmark"` database table and deploy your content.